# Content (one word) is wider than page on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

On my page, I have a title, and if that title is longer, it will go out of the page on mobile.

For example:

```
<div class="module-head"><h3 class="module-head-title">Keresőoptimalizálás - Miért éri meg?</h3></div>

    .module-head {
    text-align: left;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 40px 0;
}
.module-head-title {
    color: var(--main_purple_color);
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
.module-head:after {    
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background:  var(--main_red_color);
    width: 220px;
    max-width: 260px;
    height: 3px;
}
```

And i show a photo of the problem:
[image: Click here]

What should I do if I don't want to set a smaller font size?

Comment: I think your long word in the headline is breaking your width. You can either set word-break: break-all; on your headline or add &shy; in the text of it or use a lib like Hypher https://github.com/bramstein/hypher

Comment: And smaller font size? Can it be  a solution for this?

Comment: Yes that should work, but only to a certain extent, as a longer word will break it again

Comment: For long words that cause extra space, you can use `word-wrap: break-word;`, but I'm not sure about the cause of the problem here, since the full code of provided output -which is in a picture- is not here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language of that website, but you *can* use a `&shy` entity (called a "soft hyphen") inside the word (at an appropriate position) to break it **only when it doesn't fit into its container**.

As an example here's a long nonsense word, once *with* and once *without* a soft hyphen:

```html
<h2>Runununufanlaerlknadlknalknaelknalkneflknalkneflknaelfknaelfknaeflknaelfknoaeiruodiulsk</h2>
<h2>Runununufanlaerlknadlknalknaelknalkneflkn&shy;alkneflknaelfknaelfknaeflknaelfknoaeiruodiulsk</h2>

<h3>The same word including the soft hyphen, but with a smaller font (fits into one line, therefore it's not being broken by the soft hyphen):</h3>
<p>Runununufanlaerlknadlknalknaelknalkneflkn&shy;alkneflknaelfknaelfknaeflknaelfknoaeiruodiulsk</p>
```

If there is enough horizontal space, the word won't be divided, if not, it will be divided at the position of the soft hyphen.